# Cuda Unknown Error(ErrNo: 30) on cudaMalloc()

Tags: cuda, malloc

I have searched for the reason but no luck. It fails on such a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int* n;
  cout << cudaMallocManaged(&n, 4 * sizeof(int)) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The return code is 30, unknown error. `cudaMalloc` also fails with same code.

This is my hardware:

```
$ lspci | grep NV
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)

$ nvidia-smi
Sat Mar  7 14:02:04 2015       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 331.113    Driver Version: 331.113        |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVS 5200M           Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   53C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |    279MiB /  1023MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.10, with CUDA 6.0 from official repository(hopefully, if Ubuntu does not mess it up).

It is a Lenovo T430s labtop, the card is on Optimus so that might cause some problem. I have tested on another machine and the same code works.

**Update 1**

OK, `nvidia_uvm` is not loaded...

```
$ lsmod |grep nv

nvidia              10744914  65 
nvram                  14362  1 thinkpad_acpi
drm                   310919  6 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia

$ sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:816 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia_331_updates_uvm'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_331_updates_uvm': Function not implemented
```

**Update 2**

OK, I reinstalled nvidia-331-updates-uvm and the module was loaded.

```
$ lsmod | grep nv
nvidia_uvm             34855  0 
nvidia              10744914  66 nvidia_uvm
nvram                  14362  1 thinkpad_acpi
drm                   310919  6 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia
```

However, the code still returns error 30.

**Update 3**

After some more testing (mainly tried running as root), now I get error 71: operation not supported. However, if I am just using `cudaMalloc` it succeeded. I will also check whether my device support unified memory addressing.

**Update 4**

OK, my card only supports SM 2.1, so it does not support Unified Memory.

Comment: Have you run your program with `optirun`, like `optirun ./a.out`?

Comment: No, I am *not* using bumblebee, but the nvidia-prime using the NVidia card.

Comment: Does `nvidia_uvm` kernel module is loaded? What is in `lsmod  | grep nv` output?

Comment: Well, no... but I fail loading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `nvidia_uvm` kernel module is required for CUDA to work.

You need to install package with that kernel module, e.g. `nvidia-331-uvm` and 
enable it's autoloading by installing `nvidia-modprobe` package:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe nvidia-331-uvm
```

If you don't want to reboot after installing `nvidia-modprobe`, you can try to run your program as root (e.g. `sudo ./a.out`) — module should be loaded during run as root.